# Hosting web site using setup project

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, setup-project

I want to create .NET setup project such that it can install desktop application and after that Host website on IIS . the setup will be used in the hosting server

is it applicable in .NET if yes how to do that , and can I change IIS settings

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I need the start idea, I searched a lot but I failed

Comment: I updated my QUestion please check I need to create .NET set up project

Comment: It's not feasible to create a setup project in .NET or any other programming language. An installation is a very complex process, so it's easier to use an existing installer engine like Windows Installer. Basically, you can create an MSI package which does what you need. You can use a Visual Studio Web Setup Project or a commercial setup authoring tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a Visual Studio [Web Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kzx145%28VS.80%29.aspx) or try a different [setup authoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) which supports IIS.

After you decide on a setup tool, try to configure your installer the way you want. If you encounter problems, try asking more specific questions.

Comment: I updated my QUestion please check I need to create .NET set up project